# Regex check if specific multiple words present in a sentence

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pattern-matching

Is there a regex for us to check if multiple words are present in a string

Ex :

```
sentence = "hello i am from New York city"
```

I want to check if 'hello' 'from' and 'city' are present in sentence.

I have tried using

```
re.compile("hello|from|city")
```

but no luck as it returns true if even a single match is found.

Comment: I don't know python, but you can try something like this `(?=hello)(?=from)(?=city)` which works in perl

Comment: @mankowitz That wouldn't work, because if a position is immediately followed by `hello`, for example, it necessarily won't be immediately followed by `from` as well.

Comment: Sorry: `(?=.*hello)(?=.*from)(?=.*city)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't alternate, because then a match for any of the alternations would fulfill the regex. Instead, use multiple lookaheads from the start of the string:

```
sentence1 = "hello i am from New York city"
sentence2 = "hello i am from New York"
regex = re.compile(r"^(?=.*hello)(?=.*from)(?=.*city)")
print(regex.match(sentence1))
print(regex.match(sentence2))
```

Output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `all()` built in method.

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

Effectively the function takes an `iterable` type as a parameter.

Example:

```
words = ["hello", "from", "city"]
if all(word in 'hello from the city' for word in words):
  # Do Something
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using regex, just checking entrance of each word (from `words`) in `sentence`:

```
sentence = "hello i am from New York city"
words = ['hello', 'from', 'city']
all([w in sentence.split() for w in words])
```

In my opinion, this way is preferable because of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
>>> sentence = "hello i am from New York city"
>>> def f(s):
    return all(s.split().__contains__(i) for i in ['hello','from','city'])

>>> f(sentence)
True
```